# Voltar arquivos deletados no Git

Tags: git, terminal

Amigos, boa tarde.

Removi alguns arquivos dentro do servidor, porém preciso deles novamente, tenho eles no repositorio do git.

Como faço para ele fazer o redownload dos arquivos do repositorio?

Comment: Se você quiser voltar para o último commit, pode usar `git rebase HEAD`

Answer (score 3):

Use `$ git checkout chave` onde a palavra chave é o numero do branch numa fase onde existia seus arquivos.
Ex: `$ git checkout bc39326028de55653c8245cb7077b44023239735`
Nesse momento vc vai ver o seus arquivos de volta. Copie esses arquivos fora da sua pasta controlada por GIT e volte para a sua versão que estava antes.
Use novamente `$ git checkout aChaveInicial`.
Passe os arquivos que vc copiou fora do diretório para a posição desejada.
Faça um `$ git add .` e depois comite `$ git commit -m "arquivos de volta"`.
Pronto, os seus arquivos estáo de volta e com a última versáo do seu projeto.

Para poder vizualizar melhor as datas e as chaves use o `$gitk`

Answer (score 2):

Basta você reverter o commit que usou para excluir os arquivos.

```
git revert <commit>
```

Onde `<commit>` é o número do commit que deseja desfazer.

Documentação do [Git Revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert).

Comment: Thiago, eu não usei nenhum commit para deletar os arquivos.
Apenas deletei no local, queria fazer ele fazer um replace do repositório para o local.

Teria como atualizar como o repositorio apenas o que deletei

Comment: Já tentou fazer um novo Pull do repositório para seu local?

Answer (score 2):

Eu acho que eu utilizaria esse comando:

```
 git reset --hard HEAD
```